# Redux Obserable - RXjs - If statement

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Well I have a pipe nested in another pipe, and there i want to map an observable an provide an if statement , which , if is true , return an action and if is not then return another action

For an example I want to make this

```
export const itemAddRequest = (action$, state$) => {
  const newState$ = from(state$.value.ids);
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType("ADD_ITEM_REQUEST"),
    mergeMap(action =>
      newState$.pipe(
        map(value => {
          if (value === action.payload.id) {
            mapTo(addItemSuccess());
          } else {
            mapTo(addItemFailed());
          }
        })
      )
    )
  );
};
```

Any Ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. You can just return the action directly from the `map()` operator, since `redux-observable` needs to get an `Observable<Action>` as the final value.

```
export const itemAddRequest = (action$, state$) => {
  const newState$ = from(state$.value.ids);
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType("ADD_ITEM_REQUEST"),
    mergeMap(action =>
      newState$.pipe(
        map(value => {
          return value === action.payload.id
            ? addItemSuccess()
            : addItemFailed();
        })
      )
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: This is not working for some reason, I need to call addItemSuccess(action.payload) , like that , i Dont know if this is making any trouble

Comment: @Kazahi That's fine. If that is how you defined your action creator functions, then that is correct. I was just copying what you had in your code sample in the question. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please click the tick mark to mark it as resolved.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks then my friend , I am gonna make this code works for sure!